# Set Constant Notification Dot Color

Tags: root-access, notifications, 8.0-oreo

I have noticed the new version of Android has notification dots.

The new multicolor dots I find frustrating.   I would prefer if I could set one color for all notification dots(like red for example).

Answer (score 3):

- From [Android Developer blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/whats-new-in-android-o-developer.html?m=1)

> ....we even extract the color of the dot from your icon.

- From Stack Overflow, [Is it possible to change the notification Dot's color on Android Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46702802), accepted answer says the same with support in comments saying that it changes with icon design

So, not possible

Comment: Even with root?

Comment: I haven't found anything with root on XDA

Comment: I think theoretically a solution with Xposed could be viable as well. If you use it.

Comment: I prefer notification dots with respect to app icon color. In my stock moto launcher, it showed only in single color(light green), so I changed launcher to Nova launcher, which is now shows based on app icon color.

Comment: @Namnodorel Now that P is out I'll probably upgrade to that now which I don't believe has xposed support.

Answer (score 3):

*In complement to what [beeshyams](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/131553/beeshyams) reply:*

## 1.Answer:

**As of now, you can't change Oreo Notification dots colors in AOSP**, starting from Android 8.0, native **Notification Dot** color depends on its app icon colors.

I said AOSP, because some mobile manufactures are using their own UI apps (Launcher/ Theme apps etc... ), thus they can control Notification dots like Nova Launcher.

## 2.Workaround:

You can use  **[Nova Launcher Prime](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher.prime&hl=en)** with **[TeslaUnread](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.notifier)**. with its built-in notification dots (also with number of notifications) and you can change and choose a constant color too.

- Unfortunately the option of **Notification badges** is not available in the free version.

## 3.Example:

This example is using **Numeric Badges**, you can change the Numeric Badges to **None**, **Dynamic Badges** or **Dots** as seen in Android O.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is unread count and not badge color you are changing.